# how to compile c++ program using boost/shared_ptr.hpp on linux with g++

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, dynamic-linking

I have written a program using boost `shared_ptr` header file. How to compile this program? what library i mention with `-l` option of g++ while compiling.

Comment: Not answering the question but may answering your problem: std::shared_ptr<> are now supported by the standard library just `#include <memory>`.

Answer (score 6):

Specify the directory that contains the `boost` directory that contains the header files. For example:

- boost installation:

  > /home/user/boost_1_53_0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp
- to include:

  ```
  #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
  ```
- to compile (note [`-I`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Directory-Options.html), not `-l`):

  > g++ -I /home/user/boost_1_53_0 main.cpp -o main

Note that there is no *dynamic-linking* required, as [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) is a template and is fully defined in the header file.

If your compiler supports C++11, use [`std::shared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead (as commented by Roee):

- to include:

  ```
  #include <memory> // use std::shared_ptr<T>
  ```
- to compile:

  > g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main

Comment: Note that the `-I` here is the capital letter i for specifying include directories (in the question, the OP had written a lowercase L, which is not needed).

Comment: @interjay, yes. That is an `-I` in my answer, though it is not clear as in the comment.